# Tree structure in javascript with Json formatter

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

```
author: [
            {
                id: '1',
                code: 'ghj:aws:aws_vpc:create',
                description: 'Permission to create',
                status: 'ACTIVE',
                scope: 'PROVIDER'
            },
            {
                id: '2',
                code: 'ghj:aws:aws_vpc:update',
                description: 'Permission to create',
                status: 'ACTIVE',
                scope: 'PROVIDER'
            },
            {
                id: '3',
                code: 'ghj:aa:aa:update',
                description: 'Permission',
                status: 'ACTIVE',
                scope: 'PROVIDER'
            },
            {
                id: '4',
                code: 'dusk:resource-management:compute:ip:list',
                description: 'Permission',
                status: 'ACTIVE',
                scope: 'PROVIDER'
            },
            {
                id: '5',
                code: 'dusk:resource-management:storage:disk:delete',
                description: 'Permission',
                status: 'ACTIVE',
                scope: 'PROVIDER'
            },
            {
                id: '6',
                code: 'dusk:resource-management:storage:disk:Update',
                description: 'Permission',
                status: 'ACTIVE',
                scope: 'PROVIDER'
            }
]
```

i want to convert this tree structure like this in javascript

```
[
    {
      text: 'ghj',
      children: [
        {
          text: 'aws',
           children: [
           {
          text: 'aws_vpc',
          children: [
            {
              text: 'create'
            },
            {
              text: 'Update'
            }
          ]
        }
        ]
        
        },
          {
          text: 'aa',
           children: [
           {
          text: 'aa',
          children: [
          
            {
              text: 'Update'
            }
          ]
        }
        ]
        
        }
      ]
    }
]
```

Comment: what is going wrong?

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? Where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: show your code.